# Support for citations

Tags: feature-request, citations

One feature that I would like to see on this site would be some explicit support for citing scientific papers in the markdown syntax. In the simplest form this might be something like footnotes, in a more advanced form maybe some integration into [Pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/) or similar databases.

**Example:** According to [Nikolova et al.<sup>1</sup>](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature09775) DNA can form transient Hogsteen base pairs ...

I know that we can achieve most of that by manually linking to the relevant articles. But I think an explicit option would encourage citing primary literature, which would improve the quality of this site. Manually creating a citation like my example is also a lot of work, it would be nice if the information could be automatically extracted given a Pubmed ID or by uploading/pasting a BibTex or RIS citation file.

An integration of [DOI](http://www.doi.org/)-linking could also be useful.

Some other sites, like physics or maths, would probably also benefit from functionality like this.

The code of the example citation in this post is

```
<sub>[\[1\] Nikolova et al., Transient Hoogsteen base pairs 
in canonical duplex DNA, *Nature* **470**, 498-502 (2011)][4]</sub>
```

---

<sub>[[1] Nikolova et al., Transient Hoogsteen base pairs in canonical duplex DNA, *Nature* **470**, 498-502 (2011)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature09775)</sub>

Comment: Oh goodness yes. I've been bodging references with web page links, but it's far less than ideal.

Comment: Without editing privileges it is impossible to see source of your footnotes (I am not sure how much it is important in this case, but it may be not obvious to you, as you can always edit your own post).

Comment: @Suma You mean you can't see where the link goes? I'm not doing anything really fancy there, it should just be a link to the article

Comment: No, I can see the link just find, I just cannot see the code you have used to produce the link. If you say there is nothing fancy, the I am probably not missing much.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the current form? It seems very close to how references are working in a plain text, I can hardly imagine anything even friendlier. Example:

- this is a text [[MDL](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link)].

From source:

```
- this is a text [[MDL]].

[MDL]: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link
```

Comment: You are talking about references to URLs. OP is talking about references to academic articles.