# References for the better informed.

Tags: discussion, references

I am fortunate to know about a variety of things and, sometimes, know a little more about a few things that the internet doesn't always have accurate, up-to-date information on. For some of these things, my education plays a major role and while a standard bibliography can handle most information taken from textbooks, for example, accurate information can also be found in paywalled publications, ongoing studies and so on. Basically, not everything has an answer on the internet and some things don't even have answers in textbooks.

So, my question is, how should someone answering a question, and needing to give a resource, deal with things that are related to their degree, or other education, or things they have specialized information on, that the internet is still inadequate in providing references for?

Answer (score 5):

Provide a reference you have. There is nothing wrong with providing references to books or paywalled papers, there is no rule the references should be to web only. See [Support for citations](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/support-for-citations) for a discussion how to write non-web references.

Answer (score 1):

IMO - Unless you're providing all of the data, referencing an ongoing study isn't very useful.

Regarding, 'being an expert', the key is to provide enough information so that someone can reach a decision for themselves. Any expert is going to be able to make a logical sounding argument for just about anything in their field, accurate or not.  Unless those statements can be backed up with something other than sounding good they're not *as* useful.  Still useful, just not as useful.