# Too many links in a first timer's answer?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove number of links restriction for new users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367/remove-number-of-links-restriction-for-new-users)

So my wife likes to debunk the whole Roswell UFO non-sense, and she tried to make an answer.  When she hit submit, the site told her she had too many links and couldn't include pictures.  it was all I could do to keep her from closing the browser and just telling stack exchange to kiss her grits...

Isn't that a rather silly rule to impose on a first timer who may have a great answer as their first contribution?  And wouldn't it prevent a person from earning reputation on an answer that doesn't have the requisite citations, thereby preventing them from getting to the point of actually being able to submit a good enough answer?  Sort of a catch-22.

I would suggest this requirement be relaxed for this site in particular.

Comment: I agree that this restriction can cause a spectacularly bad first user experience here, I've tried to have it removed and I'm making a new try now.

Comment: You didn't want to hear the names my wife called Stack Exchange after she put so much into her answer.  I had to rescue it as she just walked away.  Not sure if she will come back...

Comment: Totally agree. There are plenty of posts on meta decrying how off-putting our attitude is to new users. Who cares, when the site takes care of that by itself?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I was planning to discuss this issue again with someone from the community team once I get the chance to. They're having some big meeting this week though, so they're not really available for non-emergencies right now.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella just break the URLs and ask someone to edit them `ww w.example. com`

Comment: @ajax333221 It was my wife answering.  If she has to "waste" any time and effort, she will quickly kick the offending site tot he curb...

Comment: @LarianLeQuella, What are some examples of these "names" are you talking about?