# Should we enable support for citations?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

See also the (unrelated) question: [Support for citations](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/support-for-citations)

Should we enable support for sharing our questions and answers via BibTeX, amsrefs citations?

Here's how it looks on mathoverflow:

[image: citations step 1]

[image: citations step 2]

Comment: I don't expect our posts to be cited heavily in academic works, we're really more of a popular science site. I'd really like some support for the opposite (citing scientific journals in our posts here), but I don't think we need the ability to cite our own posts.

Comment: @Fabian: Is that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The site has an express policy of "[no original research](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/faq-must-all-answers-be-referenced)".

As such, as Fabian's comment noted, I don't think any scientific publication would have a need to cite material from here, as opposed to whatever papers the answers here are citing directly.